# Re-enable disabled items in a listbox

Tags: javascript

I am trying to write a stand alone javascript, where I first select (either single or multiple) items from the list box and assign my name in the text box called DBA.

This creates line entries at the bottom depending # of "selected".
Now when I "Delete" the row, I am not able to re-enable the deleted list box items.
Here is my code:

```
<form name="myform" action="" method="get" id="myform">
    <table border="1" cellpadding="10" cellspacing="0" id="table1">
        <tr>
            <td valign="top"><input type="button" value="Selected" onclick="addRow();" />
                <br />
                <select name="selSea" id="selSeaShells" size="5" multiple="multiple">
                  <option value="ORANGE" selected="selected">
                    ORANGE
                  </option>

                  <option value="APPLE" selected="selected">
                    APPLE
                  </option>

                  <option value="GRAPE" selected="selected">
                    GRAPE
                  </option>

                  <option value="BANANA" selected="selected">
                    BANANA
                  </option>

                  <option value="TREE" selected="selected">
                    TREE
                  </option>

                  <option value="TEST" selected="selected">
                    TEST
                  </option>

                  <option value="NEWS" selected="selected">
                    NEWS
                  </option>

                  <option value="SKY" selected="selected">
                    SKY
                  </option>
                </select>
            </td>

            <td valign="top"><input type="text" id="DBA" name="DBA" value="" /> DBA</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[
    <!--

    function addRow()
    {
        var tbody = document.getElementById('table1').getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0];
        var DBAValuesObj = document.myform.DBA.value;
        var selectedArray = new Array();
        var selObj = document.getElementById('selSeaShells');
        var i;
        var count = 0;
        for (i=0; i<selObj.options.length; i++) {
            if (selObj.options[i].selected) {
                selObj.options[i].disabled = 'disabled';
                selectedArray[count] = selObj.options[i].value;
                count++;
            }
        }
        tbody.value = selectedArray + "." + DBAValuesObj;

        var row = document.createElement('TR');
        var cell1 = document.createElement('TD');
        var cell2 = document.createElement('TD');
        var inp1 = document.createElement('INPUT');
        var inp2 = document.createElement('INPUT');
        inp1.setAttribute('type','text');
        inp1.setAttribute('name','PartIDArray[]');
        inp1.setAttribute('size','15');
        inp1.setAttribute('maxlength','20');
        inp1.setAttribute('value','');

        inp1.setAttribute('value',tbody.value); 

        inp2.setAttribute('type','button');
        inp2.setAttribute('value','Delete');
        inp2.onclick=function(){delRow(this);}
        cell1.appendChild(inp1);
        row.appendChild(cell1);
        cell2.appendChild(inp2);
        row.appendChild(cell2);
        tbody.appendChild(row);
    }

    function delRow(button)
    {
        var row = button.parentNode.parentNode;
        var tbody = document.getElementById('table1').getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0];


        var selArray = new Array();
        var selObject = document.getElementById('selSeaShells');
        var i;
        var count = 0;
        for (i=0; i<selObject.options.length; i++) {
            if (selObject.options[i].selected) {
               selObject.options[i].disabled = '';
                selArray[count] = selObject.options[i].value;
               count++;
            }
        }

    tbody.removeChild(row);
    }

    //-->
    //]]>
</script>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "I am not able to re enable the deleted list box items". I see your code working. If I delete, the row is deleted and the item is available in the list box again for selection

Comment: @hop - When you click to add an item, then delete it from the added section, those items are no longer selectable (because they are disabled) from the options list.

Answer (score 0):

This is because your logic is wrong. When re enabling the items, you are iterating over the selected items.

Scenario 1 - You select APPLE. Click Selected. Click Delete. --> You will see APPLE is enabled.

Scenario 2 - You select APPLE. Click Selected. Select ORANGE. Click Delete. --> You will see APPLE is **NOT** enabled.

So you need to remember what elements you are deleting to re enable them. And `selObject.options[i].disabled = '';` will work. Its technically correct. But, the logic is bad.

The working code:

```
<form NAME="myform" action="" method="get">
<table border="1" cellpadding="10" cellspacing="0" id="table1">
<tr>
<td valign="top">
<input type="button" value="Selected" onclick="addRow();" />
<br />
<select name="selSea" id="selSeaShells" size="5" multiple="multiple">
<option value="ORANGE" selected>ORANGE</option>
<option value="APPLE" selected>APPLE</option>
<option value="GRAPE" selected>GRAPE</option>
<option value="BANANA" selected>BANANA</option>
<option value="TREE" selected>TREE</option>
<option value="TEST" selected>TEST</option>
<option value="NEWS" selected>NEWS</option>
<option value="SKY" selected>SKY</option>
</select>
</td>
<td valign="top">
<input type="text" id="DBA" NAME="DBA" VALUE="" />
DBA
</td>

</tr>
</table>
</form>

<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
<!--

function addRow()
{
var tbody = document.getElementById('table1').getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0];
var DBAValuesObj = document.myform.DBA.value;
var selectedArray = new Array();
var selObj = document.getElementById('selSeaShells');
var i;
var count = 0;
for (i=0; i<selObj.options.length; i++) {
if (selObj.options[i].selected) {
       selObj.options[i].disabled = 'disabled';
selectedArray[count] = selObj.options[i].value;
       count++;
}
}
tbody.value = selectedArray + "." + DBAValuesObj;


var row = document.createElement('TR');
var cell1 = document.createElement('TD');
var cell2 = document.createElement('TD');

var inp1 = document.createElement('INPUT');
var inp2 = document.createElement('INPUT');
inp1.setAttribute('type','text');
inp1.setAttribute('name','PartIDArray[]');
inp1.setAttribute('size','15');
inp1.setAttribute('maxlength','20');
inp1.setAttribute('value','');

inp1.setAttribute('value',tbody.value); 

inp2.setAttribute('type','button');
inp2.setAttribute('value','Delete');
inp2.onclick=function(){delRow(this);}
cell1.appendChild(inp1);
row.appendChild(cell1);
cell2.appendChild(inp2);
row.appendChild(cell2);

var cell3 = document.createElement('INPUT');
cell3.setAttribute('type','HIDDEN');
cell3.setAttribute('value',selectedArray);

row.appendChild(cell3);

tbody.appendChild(row);
}
       function delRow(button)
{
var row = button.parentNode.parentNode;
var tbody = document.getElementById('table1').getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0];


var selArray = new Array();
var selObject = document.getElementById('selSeaShells');
var i;
var count = 0;
for (i=0; i<selObject.options.length; i++) {
if (selObject.options[i].value.indexOf(row.childNodes[2].value)>-1) {

       selObject.options[i].disabled = '';
       selArray[count] = selObject.options[i].value;
       count++;
}
}


tbody.removeChild(row);
}

//-->
</script>
```

Comment: How do I fix this logic ? I am almost there...I cant put my finger on it.

Comment: I would suggest you have a hidden in each row along with your 'text' and 'button'. In ondelete(), get the value of this hidden, a csv. Find the elements in the list box to match these value and set disabled = false.

Comment: Can you give me an example of how to have a hidden in each row and get the value

Comment: Working code updated to the answer. You may need to clean up something that you are not using.

Comment: oh yes ..nice very nice....Thank you ..I have a basic java script book...this was very nice of you to help me with the syntax.